# Read same line two times using Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

In a class I have a method `replay` where I create a `Scanner` object `sc`. 
That `Scanner` object reads the first word in a line from a file.
I then pass that `Scanner` object to a method in another class. In that method I want to read the rest of the numbers in the line.

The file consists of data like this:

```
Cat 2 4

Dog 3 1

Bird 2 5

Cow 4 1
```

The first method reads "Cat", the second method reads "2" and "4".

My problem is that in the second method I once again use `sc.nextLine()`, which makes the `Scanner` jump to the next line, and not the line it started with (in the first method).

How can I make `Scanner` stay on the same line as in the beginning?

(Note, it is instructions in the assignment that I need to pass the Scanner-object to the new method, so that's nothing I can change).

Class Inline:

```
public class Inline {

    public void replay() {
        String line = "";
        File file = new File("myFile.txt");
        Scanner sc = null;
        String firstWord = null;

        try {
            sc = new Scanner(file);
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                line = sc.nextLine();
                String parts[] = line.trim().split("\\s+");  
                firstWord = parts[0];                    
                Command moveCommand = new MoveCommand();
                moveCommand.load(sc);                   **//HERE I PASS SCANNER-OBJECT TO LOAD**
             }
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
}
```

Class MoveCommand:

```
public class MoveCommand implements Command {

    private int second;
    private int third;

    public MoveCommand() {}            


    @Override
    public void load(Scanner sc) {
        String line = "";
        line = sc.nextLine();              **//HERE I USE SC.NEXTLINE() AGAIN. IS THERE ANOTHER WAY???**
        String parts[] = line.trim().split("\\s+");                
        second = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
        third = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);                    
    }    
}
```

Comment: what are you allowed to change?

Comment: why not use `next()` instead?

Comment: @DHall I can change things in the methods, as long as I pass sc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Scanner` can read token by token. A token is a part of the input which is split with the delimiter.

From the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

> A `Scanner` breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace. The resulting tokens may then be converted into values of different types using the various `next` methods.

Since your `String`s already need to be broken by whitespaces, your job is almost done.

Try to get an idea from this (I don't want to solve it for you):

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input = "Cat 3 4";

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(input);
        System.out.println(sc.next());

        load(sc);
    }

    static void load(Scanner sc) {

        System.out.println(sc.next());
        System.out.println(sc.next());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Cat
3
4
```

Comment: I applied your code to my program and it works. Thank you :-)